# passing the current Window as a CommandParameter

Tags: wpf, binding, commandparameter

how can I pass the window I am currently on as a parameter to a command?

I like to do this in XAML-markup:

```
<Button Command="CommandGetsCalled" CommandParameter="-this?-" />
```

Comment: Why? There is no "this" notation in XAML as far as I know. Besides, `this` in this case would probably be the button.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: with -this- I meant the containing Window object. I write it in the title and in in the text, that I want to pass the window. As the answers of Rachel and Daniel Pratt show, its clear enough ;)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There are two ways I can of think to do this: Give the window a name (via a `x:Name` attribute on the `Window` tag, and then construct a binding like this (assumes the name of the window is 'ThisWindow'):

```
<Button Command="CommandGetsCalled" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ThisWindow}" />
```

For something more general (doesn't rely on giving the current Window a name), the binding can be constructed like this:

```
<Button Command="CommandGetsCalled" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

Comment: Can you please show me how this could look like in the viewmodel?

Answer (score 24):

You could try binding to a RelativeSource

If you want to pass the Button as a parameter:

```
<Button Command="CommandGetsCalled" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

If you want to pass the Window as a parameter:

```
<Button Command="CommandGetsCalled" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={
             RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you Rachel. I looked at your and Daniel Pratt's solutions. Actually they are quite similar. But I'll mark his as answer, because I like the idea of accessing the Window via its name.

Comment: I'm getting `Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget.` when I try to use the `Button` as a parameter example. any ideas?

Comment: found out it's because I was trying to `.Dump()` the button in the `canExecute` via `LinqPad` which would wpf display it

Answer (score 7):

In my situation none of the provided answers worked.

This worked for me:

```
<window x:Name="myWindow">
 <Button Command="Command" CommandParameter={x:Reference Name=myWindow}/>
</window>
```