# Close window wpf in Revit

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, revit

I have to click button, that save changes and close window.

```cs
public BaseCommand SaveCommand => saveCommand ?? (saveCommand = new BaseCommand(SaveMetod, SaveCanMetod));
private bool SaveCanMetod() => IsSelectedCamera && (SelectedCamera.Height != CameraHeight || SelectedCamera.Width != CameraWidth);

        private void SaveMetod()
        {
            if (SaveCanMetod())
            {
                SelectedCamera.Width = CameraWidth.Value;
                SelectedCamera.Height = CameraHeight.Value;                
                //Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();

            }
        }
```

The string "Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();" don't work when I start my application on revit.

Comment: Are you want close whole app or just a window?

Comment: @AmRo I am want close just a window

Comment: You can pass the window as a command parameter and close it after your jobs done. To passing window as a command parameter see this example [Passing the current Window as a CommandParameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3504631/11219312).

Comment: I don't understand what I can do this, I already pass my SaveCommand
<Button Content="Ok" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example.

in xaml:

```xml
<Window Name="ThisWindow">
.
.
.
<Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ThisWindow}" />
```

in code behind:

```cs
private void SaveMethod(object paramter)
{
    var currentWindow = (Window)paramter;
    // TODO: ...
    currentWindow.Close();
}
```

and command:

```cs
public class RelayCommand : ICommand    
{    
    private Action<object> execute;    
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;    

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged    
    {    
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }    
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }    
    }    

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)    
    {    
        this.execute = execute;    
        this.canExecute = canExecute;    
    }    

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)    
    {    
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);    
    }    

    public void Execute(object parameter)    
    {    
        this.execute(parameter);    
    }    
}
```

Comment: I write my code with using MVVM pattern, and have many classes

Comment: I think you pass the User Control as parameter instead of Window. Place your window Xaml codes that's contains this button.